# Webdriver is not going to the next link Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

So, here is the deal: I have this code, it get's a link, open it, get the image, download it to my desktop and then go to the next link of the list.

For some reason when it goes to the next link it doesn't "press enter" in the navigator, it puts the link there but it doesn't go to the next website. Does anyone know how to fix it? The code is working perfectly, but this is ruining the code. Thanks!

Ps: the two "print' i putted to see if the code was going on or not, but the case is that it isn't pressing enter in the webdriver.

```
##Preparar variáveis

time.sleep(1) 
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("C:/Users/Luís/Desktop/PEBTXT/linkdasimagens.txt")]
x = 0

##Loop para abrir imagens

while True:
    try:        
        time.sleep(3)
        y = lines[x]
        driver.get(y)

        ###Pegar imagem

        img = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='BRnoselect']")
        src = img.get_attribute('src')
        with open(("C:/Users/Luís/Desktop/PEBTXT/file{}.jpg".format(x)), "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(src).content)
        print(x)
        x += 1
        print(x)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```